# Function to return date of Easter for the given year

Tags: datetime, language-agnostic, calendar, computus

So, here's a funny little programming challenge. I was writing a quick method to determine all the market holidays for a particular year, and then I started [reading about Easter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Easter) and discovered just how crazy* the logic is for determining its date--the first Sunday after the [Paschal Full Moon](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paschal_Full_Moon) following the spring equinox! Does anybody know of an existing function to calculate the date of Easter for a given year?

Granted, it's probably not all **that** hard to do; I just figured I'd ask in case somebody's already done this. (And that seems very likely.)

**UPDATE**: Actually, I'm really looking for the date of **Good Friday** (the Friday *before* Easter)... I just figured Easter would get me there. And since I'm in the U.S., I assume I'm looking for the Catholic Easter? But perhaps someone can correct me on that if I'm wrong.

<sub>*By "crazy" I meant, like, *involved*. Not anything offensive...</sub>

Comment: Which Easter? Catholic, Orthodox, or Coptic?

Comment: What is the first year for which it should work correctly?

Comment: Another nice write-up about "calculating easter": http://www.simple-talk.com/community/blogs/philfactor/archive/2009/01/18/71701.aspx . And in T-SQL, of all things.

Comment: Excellent question. I'm actually embarrassed I didn't specify this at the outset; in reality, though, I'm actually not interested in *Easter* so much as Good Friday, whose date just happens to depend on Easter. I'll update the question.

Comment: @AJ: Ha, good question. Certainly some year AD... ;)

Comment: “There are many indications that the sole important application of arithmetic in Europe during the Middle Ages was the calculation of Easter's date.” – Knuth

Comment: @JohnSaunders `dateutil` supports julian, orthodox and western.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

in SQL Server Easter Sunday would look like this, scroll down for Good Friday

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.GetEasterSunday 
( @Y INT ) 
RETURNS SMALLDATETIME 
AS 
BEGIN 
    DECLARE     @EpactCalc INT,  
        @PaschalDaysCalc INT, 
        @NumOfDaysToSunday INT, 
        @EasterMonth INT, 
        @EasterDay INT 

    SET @EpactCalc = (24 + 19 * (@Y % 19)) % 30 
    SET @PaschalDaysCalc = @EpactCalc - (@EpactCalc / 28) 
    SET @NumOfDaysToSunday = @PaschalDaysCalc - ( 
        (@Y + @Y / 4 + @PaschalDaysCalc - 13) % 7 
    ) 

    SET @EasterMonth = 3 + (@NumOfDaysToSunday + 40) / 44 

    SET @EasterDay = @NumOfDaysToSunday + 28 - ( 
        31 * (@EasterMonth / 4) 
    ) 

    RETURN 
    ( 
        SELECT CONVERT 
        (  SMALLDATETIME, 
                 RTRIM(@Y)  
            + RIGHT('0'+RTRIM(@EasterMonth), 2)  
            + RIGHT('0'+RTRIM(@EasterDay), 2)  
        ) 
    ) 

END 
GO
```

**Good Friday** is like this and it uses the Easter function above

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.GetGoodFriday 
( 
    @Y INT 
) 
RETURNS SMALLDATETIME 
AS 
BEGIN 
    RETURN (SELECT dbo.GetEasterSunday(@Y) - 2) 
END 
GO
```

From here: http://web.archive.org/web/20070611150639/http://sqlserver2000.databases.aspfaq.com/why-should-i-consider-using-an-auxiliary-calendar-table.html

Comment: This only works for years 1900 - 2199.  
Before 1900 and after 2199, it deviates from NOAA's Easter calculation script.  
The benefit of this script is that it's short and sweet.  
Here's [NOAA's script](http://aa.usno.navy.mil/faq/docs/easter.php)  
Thanks for posting this.

Comment: @LDawggie The deviation between the simplified version in this answer and NOAA version indeed starts as of 1899 (April 3 1899 (simple) vs Apr  2 1899 (NOAA)). But they differ as soon as 2100 (Mar 27 2100 (Simple) vs March 28 2100 (NOAA)) I'll post an answer with the NOAA algorithm sometime later today.

Answer (score 42):

Python: using [dateutil's `easter()` function](http://labix.org/python-dateutil#head-13c68d26cb27abbe375f9b50e93733201d7bfcf9).

```
>>> from dateutil.easter import *
>>> print easter(2010)
2010-04-04
>>> print easter(2011)
2011-04-24
```

The functions gets, as an argument, the type of calculation you like:

```
EASTER_JULIAN   = 1
EASTER_ORTHODOX = 2
EASTER_WESTERN  = 3
```

You can pick the one relevant to the US.

Reducing two days from the result would give you Good Friday:

```
>>> from datetime import timedelta
>>> d = timedelta(days=-2)
>>> easter(2011)
datetime.date(2011, 4, 24)
>>> easter(2011)+d
datetime.date(2011, 4, 22)
```

Oddly enough, someone was iterating this, and published the results in [Wikipedia's article about the algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computus):

[image]

Answer (score 5):

When it came for me to write this (traffic prediction based on day of week and holiday),
I gave up on trying to write it by myself. I found it somewhere on the net. The code was public domain, but...

*sigh*

see for yourself.

```
void dateOfEaster(struct tm* p)
{
    int Y = p->tm_year;
    int a = Y % 19;
    int b = Y / 100;
    int c = Y % 100;
    int d = b / 4;
    int e = b % 4;
    int f = (b + 8) / 25;
    int g = (b - f + 1) / 3;
    int h = (19 * a + b - d - g + 15) % 30;
    int i = c / 4;
    int k = c % 4;
    int L = (32 + 2 * e + 2 * i - h - k) % 7;
    int m = (a + 11 * h + 22 * L) / 451;
    p->tm_mon = ((h + L - 7 * m + 114) / 31 ) - 1;
    p->tm_mday = ((h + L - 7 * m + 114) % 31) + 1;
    p->tm_hour = 12;
    const time_t tmp = mktime(p);
    *p = *localtime(&tmp);  //recover yday from mon+mday
}
```

Some questions are better left unasked.

I feel lucky that all moving holidays in my country are a fixed offset from the date of Easter.

Comment: I think this is actually Donald Knuth's algorithm: http://www.linuxtopia.org/online_books/programming_books/python_programming/python_ch38.html

Answer (score 3):

The SQL Server function below is more general than the accepted answer

The accepted answer is only correct for the range (inclusive) : 1900-04-15 to 2099-04-12

It uses the algorithm provided by The United States Naval Observatory (USNO)

http://aa.usno.navy.mil/faq/docs/easter.php

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.GetEasterSunday (@Y INT)
RETURNS DATETIME
AS
    BEGIN 

        -- Source of algorithm : http://aa.usno.navy.mil/faq/docs/easter.php

        DECLARE @c INT = @Y / 100
        DECLARE @n INT = @Y - 19 * (@Y / 19)
        DECLARE @k INT = (@c - 17) / 25
        DECLARE @i INT = @c - @c / 4 - (@c - @k) / 3 + 19 * @n + 15
        SET @i = @i - 30 * (@i / 30)
        SET @i = @i - (@i / 28) * (1 - (@i / 28) * (29 / (@i + 1)) * ((21 - @n) / 11))
        DECLARE @j INT = @Y + @Y / 4 + @i + 2 - @c + @c / 4
        SET @j = @j - 7 * (@j / 7)
        DECLARE @l INT = @i - @j
        DECLARE @m INT = 3 + (@l + 40) / 44
        DECLARE @d INT = @l + 28 - 31 * (@m / 4)

        RETURN 
    ( 
        SELECT CONVERT 
        (  DATETIME, 
                 RTRIM(@Y)  
            + RIGHT('0'+RTRIM(@m), 2)  
            + RIGHT('0'+RTRIM(@d), 2)  
    ) 
    )
    END 


GO
```

Answer (score 2):

VB .NET Functions for Greek Orthodox and Catholic Easter:

```
Public Shared Function OrthodoxEaster(ByVal Year As Integer) As Date
    Dim a = Year Mod 19
    Dim b = Year Mod 7
    Dim c = Year Mod 4
    Dim d = (19 * a + 16) Mod 30
    Dim e = (2 * c + 4 * b + 6 * d) Mod 7
    Dim f = (19 * a + 16) Mod 30
    Dim key = f + e + 3
    Dim month = If((key > 30), 5, 4)
    Dim day = If((key > 30), key - 30, key)
    Return New DateTime(Year, month, day)
End Function

Public Shared Function CatholicEaster(ByVal Year As Integer) As DateTime
    Dim month = 3
    Dim a = Year Mod 19 + 1
    Dim b = Year / 100 + 1
    Dim c = (3 * b) / 4 - 12
    Dim d = (8 * b + 5) / 25 - 5
    Dim e = (5 * Year) / 4 - c - 10
    Dim f = (11 * a + 20 + d - c) Mod 30
    If f = 24 Then f += 1
    If (f = 25) AndAlso (a > 11) Then f += 1
    Dim g = 44 - f
    If g < 21 Then g = g + 30
    Dim day = (g + 7) - ((e + g) Mod 7)
    If day > 31 Then
        day = day - 31
        month = 4
    End If
    Return New DateTime(Year, month, day)
End Function
```

Answer (score 1):

The below code determines Easter through powershell:

```
function Get-DateOfEaster {
    param(
        [Parameter(ValueFromPipeline)]
        $theYear=(Get-Date).Year
        )

    if($theYear -lt 1583) {
        return $null
    } else {

        # Step 1: Divide the theYear by 19 and store the
        # remainder in variable A.  Example: If the theYear
        # is 2000, then A is initialized to 5.

        $a = $theYear % 19

        # Step 2: Divide the theYear by 100.  Store the integer
        # result in B and the remainder in C.

        $c = $theYear % 100
        $b = ($theYear -$c) / 100

        # Step 3: Divide B (calculated above).  Store the
        # integer result in D and the remainder in E.

        $e = $b % 4
        $d = ($b - $e) / 4

        # Step 4: Divide (b+8)/25 and store the integer
        # portion of the result in F.

        $f = [math]::floor(($b + 8) / 25)

        # Step 5: Divide (b-f+1)/3 and store the integer
        # portion of the result in G.

        $g = [math]::floor(($b - $f + 1) / 3)

        # Step 6: Divide (19a+b-d-g+15)/30 and store the
        # remainder of the result in H.

        $h = (19 * $a + $b - $d - $g + 15) % 30

        # Step 7: Divide C by 4.  Store the integer result
        # in I and the remainder in K.

        $k = $c % 4
        $i = ($c - $k) / 4

        # Step 8: Divide (32+2e+2i-h-k) by 7.  Store the
        # remainder of the result in L.

        $l = (32 + 2 * $e + 2 * $i - $h - $k) % 7

        # Step 9: Divide (a + 11h + 22l) by 451 and
        # store the integer portion of the result in M.

        $m = [math]::floor(($a + 11 * $h + 22 * $l) / 451)

        # Step 10: Divide (h + l - 7m + 114) by 31.  Store
        # the integer portion of the result in N and the
        # remainder in P.

        $p = ($h + $l - 7 * $m + 114) % 31
        $n = (($h + $l - 7 * $m + 114) - $p) / 31

        # At this point p+1 is the day on which Easter falls.
        # n is 3 for March and 4 for April.

        $DateTime = New-Object DateTime $theyear, $n, ($p+1), 0, 0, 0, ([DateTimeKind]::Utc)
        return $DateTime
    }
}

$eastersunday=Get-DateOfEaster 2015
Write-Host $eastersunday
```

Answer (score 0):

Found this Excel formula somewhere
Assuming cell `A1` contains year e.g. 2020

```
ROUND(DATE(A1;4;1)/7+MOD(19*MOD(A1;19)-7;30)*0,14;0)*7-6
```

Converted to T-SQL lead me to this:

```
DECLARE @yr INT=2020
SELECT DATEADD(dd, ROUND(DATEDIFF(dd, '1899-12-30', DATEFROMPARTS(@yr, 4, 1)) / 7.0 + ((19.0 * (@yr % 19) - 7) % 30) * 0.14, 0) * 7.0 - 6, -2)
```

Answer (score 0):

In JS, taken from [here](https://github.com/reZach/moontool).

```js
var epoch=2444238.5,elonge=278.83354,elongp=282.596403,eccent=.016718,sunsmax=149598500,sunangsiz=.533128,mmlong=64.975464,mmlongp=349.383063,mlnode=151.950429,minc=5.145396,mecc=.0549,mangsiz=.5181,msmax=384401,mparallax=.9507,synmonth=29.53058868,lunatbase=2423436,earthrad=6378.16,PI=3.141592653589793,epsilon=1e-6;function sgn(x){return x<0?-1:x>0?1:0}function abs(x){return x<0?-x:x}function fixAngle(a){return a-360*Math.floor(a/360)}function toRad(d){return d*(PI/180)}function toDeg(d){return d*(180/PI)}function dsin(x){return Math.sin(toRad(x))}function dcos(x){return Math.cos(toRad(x))}function toJulianTime(date){var year,month,day;year=date.getFullYear();var m=(month=date.getMonth()+1)>2?month:month+12,y=month>2?year:year-1,d=(day=date.getDate())+date.getHours()/24+date.getMinutes()/1440+(date.getSeconds()+date.getMilliseconds()/1e3)/86400,b=isJulianDate(year,month,day)?0:2-y/100+y/100/4;return Math.floor(365.25*(y+4716)+Math.floor(30.6001*(m+1))+d+b-1524.5)}function isJulianDate(year,month,day){if(year<1582)return!0;if(year>1582)return!1;if(month<10)return!0;if(month>10)return!1;if(day<5)return!0;if(day>14)return!1;throw"Any date in the range 10/5/1582 to 10/14/1582 is invalid!"}function jyear(td,yy,mm,dd){var z,f,alpha,b,c,d,e;return f=(td+=.5)-(z=Math.floor(td)),b=(z<2299161?z:z+1+(alpha=Math.floor((z-1867216.25)/36524.25))-Math.floor(alpha/4))+1524,c=Math.floor((b-122.1)/365.25),d=Math.floor(365.25*c),e=Math.floor((b-d)/30.6001),{day:Math.floor(b-d-Math.floor(30.6001*e)+f),month:Math.floor(e<14?e-1:e-13),year:Math.floor(mm>2?c-4716:c-4715)}}function jhms(j){var ij;return j+=.5,ij=Math.floor(86400*(j-Math.floor(j))+.5),{hour:Math.floor(ij/3600),minute:Math.floor(ij/60%60),second:Math.floor(ij%60)}}function jwday(j){return Math.floor(j+1.5)%7}function meanphase(sdate,k){var t,t2;return 2415020.75933+synmonth*k+1178e-7*(t2=(t=(sdate-2415020)/36525)*t)-155e-9*(t2*t)+33e-5*dsin(166.56+132.87*t-.009173*t2)}function truephase(k,phase){var t,t2,t3,pt,m,mprime,f,apcor=!1;if(pt=2415020.75933+synmonth*(k+=phase)+1178e-7*(t2=(t=k/1236.85)*t)-155e-9*(t3=t2*t)+33e-5*dsin(166.56+132.87*t-.009173*t2),m=359.2242+29.10535608*k-333e-7*t2-347e-8*t3,mprime=306.0253+385.81691806*k+.0107306*t2+1236e-8*t3,f=21.2964+390.67050646*k-.0016528*t2-239e-8*t3,phase<.01||abs(phase-.5)<.01?(pt+=(.1734-393e-6*t)*dsin(m)+.0021*dsin(2*m)-.4068*dsin(mprime)+.0161*dsin(2*mprime)-4e-4*dsin(3*mprime)+.0104*dsin(2*f)-.0051*dsin(m+mprime)-.0074*dsin(m-mprime)+4e-4*dsin(2*f+m)-4e-4*dsin(2*f-m)-6e-4*dsin(2*f+mprime)+.001*dsin(2*f-mprime)+5e-4*dsin(m+2*mprime),apcor=!0):(abs(phase-.25)<.01||abs(phase-.75)<.01)&&(pt+=(.1721-4e-4*t)*dsin(m)+.0021*dsin(2*m)-.628*dsin(mprime)+.0089*dsin(2*mprime)-4e-4*dsin(3*mprime)+.0079*dsin(2*f)-.0119*dsin(m+mprime)-.0047*dsin(m-mprime)+3e-4*dsin(2*f+m)-4e-4*dsin(2*f-m)-6e-4*dsin(2*f+mprime)+.0021*dsin(2*f-mprime)+3e-4*dsin(m+2*mprime)+4e-4*dsin(m-2*mprime)-3e-4*dsin(2*m+mprime),pt+=phase<.5?.0028-4e-4*dcos(m)+3e-4*dcos(mprime):4e-4*dcos(m)-.0028-3e-4*dcos(mprime),apcor=!0),!apcor)throw"Error calculating moon phase!";return pt}function phasehunt(sdate,phases){var adate,k1,k2,nt1,nt2,yy,mm,dd,jyearResult=jyear(adate=sdate-45,yy,mm,dd);for(yy=jyearResult.year,mm=jyearResult.month,dd=jyearResult.day,adate=nt1=meanphase(adate,k1=Math.floor(12.3685*(yy+1/12*(mm-1)-1900)));nt2=meanphase(adate+=synmonth,k2=k1+1),!(nt1<=sdate&&nt2>sdate);)nt1=nt2,k1=k2;return phases[0]=truephase(k1,0),phases[1]=truephase(k1,.25),phases[2]=truephase(k1,.5),phases[3]=truephase(k1,.75),phases[4]=truephase(k2,0),phases}function kepler(m,ecc){var e,delta;e=m=toRad(m);do{e-=(delta=e-ecc*Math.sin(e)-m)/(1-ecc*Math.cos(e))}while(abs(delta)>epsilon);return e}function getMoonPhase(julianDate){var Day,N,M,Ec,Lambdasun,ml,MM,MN,Ev,Ae,MmP,mEc,lP,lPP,NP,y,x,MoonAge,MoonPhase,MoonDist,MoonDFrac,MoonAng,F,SunDist,SunAng;return N=fixAngle(360/365.2422*(Day=julianDate-epoch)),Ec=kepler(M=fixAngle(N+elonge-elongp),eccent),Ec=Math.sqrt((1+eccent)/(1-eccent))*Math.tan(Ec/2),Lambdasun=fixAngle((Ec=2*toDeg(Math.atan(Ec)))+elongp),F=(1+eccent*Math.cos(toRad(Ec)))/(1-eccent*eccent),SunDist=sunsmax/F,SunAng=F*sunangsiz,ml=fixAngle(13.1763966*Day+mmlong),MM=fixAngle(ml-.1114041*Day-mmlongp),MN=fixAngle(mlnode-.0529539*Day),MmP=MM+(Ev=1.2739*Math.sin(toRad(2*(ml-Lambdasun)-MM)))-(Ae=.1858*Math.sin(toRad(M)))-.37*Math.sin(toRad(M)),lPP=(lP=ml+Ev+(mEc=6.2886*Math.sin(toRad(MmP)))-Ae+.214*Math.sin(toRad(2*MmP)))+.6583*Math.sin(toRad(2*(lP-Lambdasun))),NP=MN-.16*Math.sin(toRad(M)),y=Math.sin(toRad(lPP-NP))*Math.cos(toRad(minc)),x=Math.cos(toRad(lPP-NP)),toDeg(Math.atan2(y,x)),NP,toDeg(Math.asin(Math.sin(toRad(lPP-NP))*Math.sin(toRad(minc)))),MoonAge=lPP-Lambdasun,MoonPhase=(1-Math.cos(toRad(MoonAge)))/2,MoonDist=msmax*(1-mecc*mecc)/(1+mecc*Math.cos(toRad(MmP+mEc))),MoonAng=mangsiz/(MoonDFrac=MoonDist/msmax),mparallax/MoonDFrac,{moonIllumination:MoonPhase,moonAgeInDays:synmonth*(fixAngle(MoonAge)/360),distanceInKm:MoonDist,angularDiameterInDeg:MoonAng,distanceToSun:SunDist,sunAngularDiameter:SunAng,moonPhase:fixAngle(MoonAge)/360}}function getMoonInfo(date){return null==date?{moonPhase:0,moonIllumination:0,moonAgeInDays:0,distanceInKm:0,angularDiameterInDeg:0,distanceToSun:0,sunAngularDiameter:0}:getMoonPhase(toJulianTime(date))}function getEaster(year){var previousMoonInfo,moonInfo,fullMoon=new Date(year,2,21),gettingDarker=void 0;do{previousMoonInfo=getMoonInfo(fullMoon),fullMoon.setDate(fullMoon.getDate()+1),moonInfo=getMoonInfo(fullMoon),void 0===gettingDarker?gettingDarker=moonInfo.moonIllumination<previousMoonInfo.moonIllumination:gettingDarker&&moonInfo.moonIllumination>previousMoonInfo.moonIllumination&&(gettingDarker=!1)}while(gettingDarker&&moonInfo.moonIllumination<previousMoonInfo.moonIllumination||!gettingDarker&&moonInfo.moonIllumination>previousMoonInfo.moonIllumination);for(fullMoon.setDate(fullMoon.getDate()-1);0!==fullMoon.getDay();)fullMoon.setDate(fullMoon.getDate()+1);return fullMoon}
```

Then run `getEaster(2020); // -> Sun Apr 12 2020`

Answer (score 0):

Oracle, gives correct Easter dates between 1900 and 2078:

```
to_date('18991230','yyyymmdd') + round((to_date(callendar_year||'04','yyyymm') -
to_date('18991230','yyyymmdd')) / 7 + mod(19 * MOD(callendar_year, 19) + 23, 30) * 0.14, 0) * 7-6
```