# How to calculate Good Friday in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

Does anyone know how to calculate the date of Good Friday in Ruby? Thanks.

Comment: Is this a homework? Have you tried to find out how to calculate Good Friday in general, independent of any programming language?

Comment: Same question for other langueges: [How can I calculate what date Good Friday falls on given a year?]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2510383/how-can-i-calculate-what-date-good-friday-falls-on-given-a-year or [Function to return date of Easter for the given year]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2192533/function-to-return-date-of-easter-for-the-given-year

Answer (score 5):

You may use a gem.

I use http://rubygems.org/gems/holidays (calculates also national holidays) Really a nice gem.

There are also:

- http://rubygems.org/gems/greek_easter
- http://rubygems.org/gems/date_easter
- http://rubygems.org/gems/when_easter

Comment: My god!!! I was looking for something like this yesterday but didn't find any. Thanks for opening my eye +1

Answer (score 4):

Yes - this has been **the** most important algorithm of the Western civilization for several centuries. See e.g. Wikipedia's article on *computus* (calculation of the date of Easter): http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computus#Algorithms . Should be trivially portable to most languages.

Comment: Neat, I didn't know finding Easter day was so complicated.

Comment: are you saying 'most important' in a joking way or are you serious?

Comment: @jaydel: Note my use of a past tense. To quote the *second sentence* of the linked Wikipedia article: "The name ['computus'] has been used for this procedure since the early **Middle Ages**, as it was one of the most important computations **of the age**." (emphasis mine) It was at the time a matter of life and death, quite literally.

Comment: I misunderstood...I thought you were saying it still was...I can see how it can have seriously impacted society in the past. I was just curious...hard to tell when someone is being serious or snarky

Comment: That article is great reading, amazing to see the development of the algorithm over time. Thanks for this.