# Need to create U.S holiday Calendar in Snowflake

Tags: date, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, dimension

Need to create U.S holiday Calendar in Snowflake to use for Date Dimension

Comment: I need to US Holiday calendar to populate data into Data Dimension table in Snowflake. Please let me know how to get the US calendar list and do the needful...

Comment: You need to provide more information then this. Holidays can be different for different year. You can generate a year calendar using synthetic rows with something like TABLE(GENERATOR(ROWCOUNT => 365) and then identify which days are holiday in that.

Comment: Hi , either you will have to identify year by year the holidays and store it in a table or you can use the  following who have  the holiday calendar , https://www.snowflake.com/datasets/sonra-date-dimension-with-global-holiday-calendar/

Comment: Correct , i will be creating the holiday list in a table. Now the issue is where can i get the entire holiday list for couple of years ??

Comment: Similar question here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58617459/easter-good-friday-for-sowflake-date-dim/58621818#58621818

Comment: every holiday follows a set of rules to calculate what day it falls on.  You can easily do this yourself, example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18326446/how-to-calculate-holidays-for-the-usa